# Embedding of the 1-skeleton of a Coxeter group into its Davis complex

Tags: group-theory, hyperbolic-geometry, geometric-group-theory, coxeter-groups

Let $(W,S)$ be a Coxeter system and let $\Sigma$ be the corresponding Davis complex. It is well-known that the Davis complex may be equipped with a piecewise Euclidean metric so that it is a proper, complete $\text{CAT}(0)$ metric  space. Being the 1-sceleton of the Davis complex, the Cayley graph of $W$ (with respect to the generating set $S$) canonically embeds into $\Sigma$.

It might be obvious, but I was wondering if this embedding sends geodesic paths (with respect to the word metric) in the Cayley graph to geodesic paths in $\Sigma$ (with respect to the piecewise Euclidean metric).

Comment: Do you know any Davis complexes?

Answer (score 2):

It does not send geodesic paths to geodesic paths. For example in the finite dihedral group case the complex is a polygon and the Cayley graph is on the boundary.

Comment: I actually am pretty sure once there are two cells there is no intrinsic metric where geodesic paths on 1-skeleton are geodesics in any reasonable complex for similar reasons. Maybe there are some other conditions needed